# Images in OpenModelica Documentation

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Following is an example of how an image is embedded in an `OpenModelica` Documentation.

```
modelica://Modelica/Resources/Images/Blocks/Sources/Constant.png\
```

Can I know what modelica: is in the code? If I am not mistaken its the `OPENMODELICALIBRARY` environment variable. Right?

Also, If I have to embed images in a model that I have created, how do I use the above format? (Currently I'm hardcoding the path to where the image exists in the model. This would be of no use say I give this library to someone else unless they keep the image in the same path)

Thanks in Advance,
MSK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is not OPENMODELICALIBRARY as that contains several Modelica libraries. Is the directory of the Modelica library that is loaded, that is OPENMODELICALIBRARY/Modelica 3.2.1/ or another one.

Read the Modelica Specification (https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec32Revision2.pdf, 13.2.3 External Resources) with regards to modelica:// URIs.
Basically modelica://LibraryName/... will lead to the actual path where library LibraryName is and what is after it will be looked up starting from that directory.

Comment: For future reference, it is also possible to access the path of a modelica:// URI using `Modelica.Utilities.Files.loadResource("modelica://...")`, which will resolve a URI at runtime if needed.